# Devise Update User does not work for boolean field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise 4.1.1 and I have added quite a few fields to the user's profile page that he/she can update. However, this one field `pure_veg` is not updating and is the only field of the type boolean.

Here is my application_controller, where I have permitted the params --

```
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_no, :date_of_birth, :sex, :marital_status, :allergy, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :address_city, :pure_veg]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end
```

I have also whitelisted the param in the users controller --

```
  def secure_params
        params.require(:user).permit( :first_name,
                                        :last_name,
                                        :date_of_birth,
                                        :age,
                                        :sex,
                                        :pure_veg,
                                        :marital_status,
                                        :address_door_no_and_street,
                                        :address_city,
                                        :address_state,
                                        :address_landmark,
                                        :height,
                                        :weight,
                                        :hip_size,
                                        :waist_size,
                                        :user_type,
                                        :status,
                                        :subscription,
                                        :allergy,
                                        :bmi,
                                        :whr,
                                        :directions,
                                        :phone_no)
    end
```

And finally, here is the registrations/edit form --

```
        = simple_form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name),                          \
          html: { method: :put, novalidate: false, class: "form-horizontal col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" } do |f| \
          #= f.error_notification
          = f.form_group :first_name do |f|
            = f.label :first_name, class: "col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label"
            .col-sm-7
              = f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true, class: "form-control"
              = f.error_messages
          = f.form_group :last_name do |f|
            = f.label :last_name, class: "col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label"
            .col-sm-7
              = f.input :last_name, required: true, autofocus: true, class: "form-control"
              = f.error_messages

          = f.form_group :email do |f|
            = f.label :email, class: "col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label"
            .col-sm-7
              = f.email_field :email, required: true, autofocus: true, class: "form-control"
              = f.error_messages

          = f.form_group :phone_no do |f|
            = f.label :phone_number, class: "col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label"
            .col-sm-7
              = f.input :phone_no, required: true, autofocus: true, class: "form-control"
              = f.error_messages

          = f.form_group :date_of_birth do |f|
            = f.label :date_of_birth, class: "col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label"
            .col-sm-7
              = f.input :date_of_birth, as: :string, input_html: {class: 'datepicker'},
                placeholder: "Date of Birth", class: "form-control", value: f.object.date_of_birth_before_type_cast.try(:strftime,"%Y/%m/%d"),
                label: false, start_year: Date.today.year - 110, end_year: Date.today.year, required: true, autofocus: true
              = f.error_messages
          = f.form_group :pure_veg do |f|
            = f.label :pure_veg, class: "col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label"
            .col-sm-7
              = f.input :pure_veg, class: "form-control"
              = f.error_messages

          = f.form_group :sex do |f|
            = f.label :sex, class: "col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label"
            .col-sm-7
              = f.input :sex, class: 'form-control', as: :select, collection: {Male: 0, Female: 1}, label: false, selected: current_user.sex_before_type_cast,
                required: true, autofocus: true
              = f.error_messages
          = f.form_group :marital_status do |f|
            = f.label :marital_status, class: "col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label"
            .col-sm-7
              = f.input :marital_status, class: "form-control", collection: {Single: 0, Married: 1, Divorced: 2, Widowed: 3},
                label: false, selected: current_user.marital_status_before_type_cast
              = f.error_messages
          = f.form_group :allergy do |f|
            = f.label :allergy, class: "col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label"
            .col-sm-7
              = f.text_area :allergy, class: "form-control"
              = f.error_messages
          = f.form_group :password do |f|
            = f.label :password, class: "col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label"
            .col-sm-7
              = f.input :password, class: "form-control"
              = f.error_messages
              .help-inline
                | Leave it blank if you dont want to change it.
          = f.form_group :password_confirmation do |f|
            = f.label :password_confirmation, class: "col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label"
            .col-sm-7
              = f.input :password_confirmation, class: "form-control"
              = f.error_messages
          = f.form_group :current_password do |f|
            = f.label :current_password, class: "col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label"
            .col-sm-7
              = f.input :current_password, class: "form-control", required: true
              = f.error_messages
              .help-inline
                | We need your current password to confirm your changes.
          .form-actions.col-sm-offset-2.mb40
            = f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

The params are also being submitted perfectly in the user object.

What am I doing wrong? The other fields update fine even.

Comment: Can you post your request payload? (The query string parameters)

Comment: Wow. Personally, I'd put all those fields in the `Profile` model. Have you made a typo by saying "user's profile"? So basically the user's profile is on the `User` model?